# The compilation of coq:list-string failed at "ruby pp.rb"

Tags: coq, opam

I am following a coq tutorial, which requires a basic coq OPAM library `coq:io:system`. But I got errors with OPAM. (This is with Ubuntu14.04, coq 8.4pl6 and opam1.2.1)

I googled around and didn't find any solution.

Does anyone know what the problem might be and how to fix this error?

Thanks.

```
=-=- Processing actions -=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
∗  installed coq:function-ninjas.1.0.0
∗  installed coq:error-handlers.1.0.0
∗  installed coq:io.3.0.0
∗  installed coq:list-plus.1.1.0
[ERROR] The compilation of coq:list-string failed at "ruby pp.rb".
∗  installed ppx_tools.0.99.2
∗  installed lwt.2.4.8
∗  installed coq:io:system:ocaml.2.2.0

#=== ERROR while installing coq:list-string.2.1.0 =============================#
# opam-version 1.2.1
# os           linux
# command      ruby pp.rb
# path         /home/zhen/.opam/system/build/coq:list-string.2.1.0
# compiler     system (4.02.1)
# exit-code    127
# env-file     /home/zhen/.opam/system/build/coq:list-string.2.1.0/coq:list-string-2159-326a35.env
# stdout-file  /home/zhen/.opam/system/build/coq:list-string.2.1.0/coq:list-string-2159-326a35.out
# stderr-file  /home/zhen/.opam/system/build/coq:list-string.2.1.0/coq:list-string-2159-326a35.err
### stdout ###
```

Comment: It's a coq HelloWorld tutorial: http://coq-blog.clarus.me/tutorial-a-hello-world-in-coq.html

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that (as the error message suggests), this particular package seems to depend on `ruby`.

I was able to finish the installation after installing `ruby` with `sudo apt-get install ruby`.